# VBA (Sum of Absolute Difference) Ranges

Tags: vba, excel

Write a function that takes 2 ranges or 2 arrays as input and gets the sum of absolute difference of every element if these two ranges/arrays have the same numbers of elements or send error message to user if the sizes of these two arrays/ranges are not the same. This is a VBA problem and I am having a rough time.

This is what I have so far:

```
Public Function MyFunction(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range)
    Dim CountRng1 As Long
    Dim CountRng2 As Long

    Rng1.Count = CountRng1
    Rng2.Count = CountRng2

    If CountRng1 = CountRng2 Then

    Else
        MsgBox "Error, the ranges you passed to the function are not the same size"
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: looks good, it is still work in progress, but what is your question?

Comment: Do the input ranges need to be the same shape (# of rows) or just the same size?

Answer (score 0):

Function don't show any popup message.  So slight changes done in your code to do your expected task.

```
Public Function MyFunction(Rng1 As Range, Rng2 As Range)
    Dim CountRng1 As Long
    Dim CountRng2 As Long

    CountRng1 = Rng1.Count
    CountRng2 = Rng2.Count

    If CountRng1 = CountRng2 Then
        'Your Code Goes here...
    Else
        MyFunction = "Error, the ranges you passed to the function are not the same size"
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple formula in a cell:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ABS(A1:A10-B1:B10))
```